# How can I generate a Point Cloud from a depth map in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, point-clouds

So I am quite new to Unity. I have a depthmap I generated with python. It consists of two arrays, one array with all the 3D points and one with the corresponding colors. I can match the points to the colors by index.

Now I want to show this depth map as a simple non-animated point cloud in unity. It is interesting to note, that the 3D-Points come from a 360° camera, so the Point cloud is supposed to be around the Unity Viewpoint.

Till now I attempted to use a mesh. I could just set the 3D points as the vertices and the colors as the colors of the mesh. Now I am having troubles defining the triangles for the mesh. When I am iterating over the points, I do not know what points in my array are the closest ones to the one I am currently looking at, because my points are not ordered. My Array for example would look like this:

```
[187 167 177]
[185 135 232]
[ 15 111 236]
[  1 111 236]
[201 167 177]
```

Even if I would order my points, my problem is, that I would have to change the color array accordingly. And even then, since my points go around the viewport, I would somehow have to decide on which side of the camera my points are, to not draw triangles through the open space.

Now my questions are: Do I have to use triangles for meshes? Is there another way to display simple Point Clouds?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"Best way..."_ might be _subject to opinion_ and if so is sadly off-topic for SO. [ask].  Consider re-phrasing your question to be [constructive subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @MickyD Thank you for pointing this out. I am quite new to Stack overflow and did not know title restrictions would be so strict. I will go ahead and change the title

Comment: FWIW, I think [MeshLab](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/tree/master) or [CloudCompare](https://github.com/CloudCompare/CloudCompare) do this somewhere in between too. The name of the steps are DepthMap, DepthMapFilter. However it's all c++

Comment: Or was it [Meshroom](https://github.com/alicevision/meshroom), which is in Python